# Jackson : Mapping different fields to one JsonProperty

Tags: java, jackson

I have a requirement wherein i have a POJO class named Response with 3 different fields and out of these 3 fields only one of them would be set based on some condition. I want that whenever any one of them is set, it should be returned with JsonProperty name 'data'. However, on defining all 3 fields with @JsonProperty("data") i am getting below exception. Is there any way i can achieve this using Jackson?

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple fields representing property "data":

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class Response {

    @JsonProperty("data")
    private List<Z> zList;

    @JsonProperty("data")
    private List<Y> yList;

    @JsonProperty("data")
    private List<x> xList;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a single getter like:

```
@JsonProperty("data")
public List getData(){
   if(zList != null){
       return zList;
   }else if(yList != null){
      return yList;
   }
   else if(xList != null) {
       return xList;
   }else{
     return Collections.emptyList(); //or whatever
  }
}
```

remember to remove the jsonproperty annotation from the fields.